# Computed column is not allowed to be used in another computed-column -- how can I allow it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Marks](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SID] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Student(ID),
    [Year] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [ExamType] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [S1] [int] null constraint s1_marks check (s1 >=0 and s1<=25),
    [S2] [int] null constraint s2_marks check (s2 >=0 and s2<=25),
    [S3] [int] null constraint s3_marks check (s3 >=0 and s3<=25),
    [S4] [int] null constraint s4_marks check (s4 >=0 and s4<=25),
    [S5] [int] null constraint s5_marks check (s5 >=0 and s5<=25),
    [TotalMarks] AS (S1+S2+S3+S4+S5),
    [Avg] AS ((S1+S2+S3+S4+S5)/5),
    [Percentage] AS (((S1+S2+S3+S4+S5)/125.0)*100),
    [Rank] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Grade] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](500) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Marks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID] ASC)
);
```

I created the about table and I want to display the Grade based on the Percentage and I created the Function for that and I dropped the existing column name is "Grade" and I Re-added the column "Grade" using alter command

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_marks DROP COLUMN Grade

ALTER TABLE tbl_Marks ADD Grade AS dbo.fn_CalculateGrade(percentage)
```

While adding the "Grade" column I got this error is:

> Msg 1759, Level 16, State 0, Line 47
> Computed column 'Percentage' in table 'tbl_Marks' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.

This is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CalculateGrade(@Percentage DECIMAL)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Grade VARCHAR(10)
    SET @Grade = (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Percentage,0) BETWEEN 60.00 AND 70.99 THEN 'D'
  WHEN ISNULL(@Percentage,0) BETWEEN 71.00 AND 80.99 THEN 'C'
  WHEN ISNULL(@Percentage,0) BETWEEN 81.00 AND 90.99 THEN 'B'
  WHEN ISNULL(@Percentage,0) BETWEEN 91.00 AND 100.00 THEN 'A' END)

    RETURN @Grade

END
GO
```

AND I try to add with out function also that query is:

```
  UPDATE tbl_Marks SET Grade= (CASE WHEN ISNULL(Percentage,0) BETWEEN 60.00 AND 70.99 THEN 'D'
  WHEN ISNULL(Percentage,0) BETWEEN 71.00 AND 80.99 THEN 'C'
  WHEN ISNULL(Percentage,0) BETWEEN 81.00 AND 90.99 THEN 'B'
  WHEN ISNULL(Percentage,0) BETWEEN 91.00 AND 100.00 THEN 'A' END)
```

How can I achieve this with out an any error?

Comment: One workaround would be to pass `S1-S5` as parameters directly and just calculate the percentage in the function.

Comment: In truth, I would avoid using a user defined scalar function as a computed column: especially as you're on 2017 so it can't be inlined. Considering its just a `CASE` expression you're probably better off just defining it in the column itself.

Comment: Yes , it is working instead of 'user defined scalar function' I used  'CASE'

Comment: I also *strongly* recommend not using a function here. It looks pretty but it's slow for all sorts of reasons. @Larnu Computed column is never inlined even on 2019, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#inlineable-scalar-udfs-requirements

Comment: I didn't say it would be, @Charlieface .

Comment: Fair warning, you have integer division in your table definition. `[Avg] AS ((S1+S2+S3+S4+S5)/5)` will be an integer. Also, you should arguably be casting to decimal to avoid floating point inaccuracies.